# How to scrape new Instagram dm's

Tags: python, instagram, scrape, dm

I want to make a script to get notified If I got a new Instagram dm.
I would ask you If there is a way to scrape all new Instagram dm's I got and read them and send the message to me.
My idea was that I use selenium and look into the messages and click on the new message and scrape it but with selenium I cant check if the message is a new one or a old one.